# Strict Standards: Accessing static property content::$total as non static

Tags: php

This is my Code:

```
class content
{
    public $text;
    public static $total;

    function __construct($content){
        $this->text = $content;
        $this->total = 0;
    }

    public static function vote(){
        self::$total++;
    }

}


$foo = new content("hai");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($foo);
echo "</pre>";

$foo::vote();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($foo);
echo "</pre>";
```

The output:

**Strict Standards**:  Accessing static property content::$total as non static in **C:\Users\jodi\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FinalProject\FinalProject\index.php** on line **10**

```
content Object
(
    [text] => hai
    [total] => 0
)
```

```
content Object
(
    [text] => hai
    [total] => 0
)
```

the `$total` is not change.
and got error. -,-

How to increment `$total`?

is there any alternative way??

Comment: You did reference the variable `$total` in the constructor as an object variable but you've declared it to be a class variable. Why is the method `vote()` declared as a class method?

Comment: Remove $this->total = 0; from constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from referencing the variable `$total` as object variable in the constructor, since you've declared it as `static`, that is a class variable.
Since I don't know the idea behind your design you have (at least) two options:
**Option 1:**
If you need `$total` as a class variable, remove the initialisation from the constructor. You could define a default value `0` and use an object method to get the value of the class variable, i.e.

```
class content
{
    public $text;
    public static $total = 0;

    function __construct($content){
        $this->text = $content;
    }

    public function getTotal() {
        return self::$total;
    }

    public static function vote(){
        self::$total++;
    }

}
```

**Option 2:**
If you don't really need it as a class variable, but a field which is different for each object you instantiate, get rid of the `static` and declare the `vote()` method as object method:

```
class content
{
    public $text;
    public $total;

    function __construct($content){
        $this->text = $content;
        $this->total = 0;
    }

    public function vote(){
        $this->total++;
    }

}
```